# Find N largest lines from a file: how would you make this better?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, numbers

I was recently rejected from a potential employer after submitting this code. They suggested I wasn't technically capable enough. I'm wondering if someone could shed light on to how to make this better/more efficient.

The question was to find the N longest lines from a file of multiple lines. This ultimately boiled down to a sorting problem, so I built an algorithm to find the N largest numbers from a list of numbers as so:

```
def selection(numbers, n):

    maximum = []

    for x in range (0, n):

        maximum.append(numbers[x])
        ind = x

        for y in range ( x, len(numbers) ):
            if numbers[y] > maximum[len(maximum)-1]:
                maximum[len(maximum)-1] = numbers[y]
                numbers[ind], numbers[y] = numbers[y], numbers[ind]

    return maximum
```

This runs in *O(n)*, unless N = n, in which case it runs in *O(n^2)*. I was surprised to hear them doubt my technical abilities, so I thought I'd bring it to you SO. How do I make this better?

**EDIT: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify: I populated a list with the line-by-line word-counts from the file, and ran it through this function.**

**EDIT2: Some people mentioned syntax. I've only been doing Python for about a day or two. My employer suggested I write it in Python (and I mentioned that I didn't know Python), so I assumed small syntax errors and methods wouldn't be such an issue.**

**EDIT3: Turns out my initial reasoning was flawed with the selection sort. I had it in my head that a min-heap would be nlogn, but I forgot that the average complexity for my code is n^2. Thanks for the help everyone.**

Comment: nice function, but it does not answer your employer's question.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? It's not exactly clear what it does unless the indentation is correct.

Comment: You should ask the employer for more feedback

Comment: Why is your first argument called ``numbers``? Shouldn't it be called ``lines``?

Comment: `maximum[len(maximum)-1]` should make any interviewer skeptical.

Comment: I don't believe your claim that this runs in O(n) is correct. This looks like O(n^2) all the way to me.

Answer (score 4):

```
from heapq import nlargest

def longest_lines(n, filename):
    with open(filename) as input:
        return nlargest(n, input, key=len)
```

Alright, addressing the comments below:

```
def longest_lines(n, filename):
    heap = []
    with open(filename) as input:
        for ln in filename:
            push(heap, ln)
            if len(heap) > n:
                pop(heap)
    return heap
```

where `push` and `pop` are the good old min-heap insert and delete-min algorithms that can be found in any textbook (and that I never get right in one go, so I'm not posting them now), comparing lines by their length. This runs in O(*N*×lg(*n*)) time where *N* is the number of lines in the file, consuming O(*n*) temporary space.

Note that the resulting list is not sorted by length, but adding that can be done by popping the elements until the heap is empty and reversing the result of that.

Comment: one can safely assume library functions are not allowed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wouldn't want a future employee of mine reinventing the wheel.

Comment: As a hiring manager, I'd want to hear that a heap should be used, but I'd also need some demonstration that the candidate understands *how* it would be used, not just point to some high-level black box they happen to know exists on their platform.

Comment: @erickson I recognized that a heap would work, but I made a calculated decision not to make use of one. Should I have mentioned that?

Comment: Shouldn't the second `if` be a `while`?

Comment: @erickson: actually, it should have been indented; the heap should never outgrow *n* + 1 elements as a loop invariant. Fixed it.

Comment: @larsmans Okay, that works. Slightly different than mine (I don't know if there's a "peek" operation for python heaps), but same basic idea and very readable.

Comment: @erickson: peek would be just `heap[0]`; I'm assuming simple lists, and so does Python's `heapq`. My algorithm is almost the same as yours, but skips one check ("if the current line is longer" -> not needed except to express a preference for lines occurring earlier in the file).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a heap, but a min-heap, not a max-heap, which may seem counterintuitive.

```
Create an empty heap.
For each line, 
  if there are less than N lines in the heap, add the current line;
  otherwise,
    if the current line is longer than the minimum element in the heap,
      remove the minimum element from the heap, and
      add the current line to the heap.
Return the contents of the heap.
```

Comment: I considered a min-heap, but wouldn't this run in `nlogn` time? In which case, in what way is it better than my solution? Thanks for the response.

Comment: erickson, heap insertion for one element is O(log(N)). So heap insertion for N elements is O(N log(N)). But @casper, even O(N log(N)) time is better than O(N^2), which is what the average complexity of your code above would be.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it would be nlogn if N = n, which it wouldn't, meaning your solution is the more effective one. My original idea was to use min-heap, but through apparantly flawed logic I reasoned the selection sort would be more efficient, even though the average complexity would be O(N^2) for mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this boil down to sorting?  If you have a list that can hold N lines, you could keep a couple of ints that hold the length of the shortest line so far found and its index in the list.  If any line is read that is longer than this line, you only need to iterate the list once to find the new shortest line and also to replace the old shortest line.