# Find n highest numbers

Tags: java

There are millions of integers are given. How to find out n largest numbers from this? Note that since the input is huge i cant store anything in the memory.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
shag

Comment: How large is `n`? Enough to store all the results in memory?

Comment: Is this a homework? If yes pls tag it so.

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9236387/166749 and several other recent questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through all numbers (reading them from a media one by one for example) and only keep a list with the 10 maximum numbers.

In pseudo code:

```
max_numbers = new int[n]
until not end of file:
    read number
    if number > min(max_numbers):
        'copy number to minimum value of max_numbers'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have an array of n elements and if you find one number that is bigger than the smallest in the array, you can change it.

You could keep an extra variable where you keep the smallest number in the array so you only iterate on it when you know you have to change something.

Answer (score 1):

Get an array of 10 length, while you run through numbers, swap the smallest with a new bigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void largest() {
    int _current, _highest, _lowest;

    if(_current >= _highest) {
       _highest = _current;
    } else if(_current <= _lowest) {
       _lowest = _current;
    }
}
```

What I would do.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a [Max-Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) of size `n`.

Comment: this will work, but it will run in Nlog(N), whereas the ideal solution can be done in N time.

Comment: @Eric: Can you please explain?

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED**

I recommend forming a priority-queue (heap based), taking Michael's suggestion to it's logical conclusion. **Don't store 10, store n.**

```
PQ a[n];
a.insert(input);
```

`O(log n)` FTW

Comment: Nope, a heap gives the answer in O(N lg n) where N is in the millions. Also, you need a [min-heap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118787/166749) for this task.

Comment: You'd have to keep all the input in memory for this unless you modified the heap to only have a predetermined maximum depth. I'd argue this makes a wikipedia link answer too vague to be helpful.

Comment: Changed my answer. Please review.

Comment: The **O(log n)** claim is still bogus. You can't not read the input. I.e. you can't get better than **O(N • log n)**, but you can't omit the factor because of that. (Disclaimer: I didn't downvote.) Also, the priority queue would still have to be bounded.

Comment: Cool fact: you can do it in O(n), but not without some really complex data structures.

Comment: You could probably get better results with a Fusion Tree, or if memory isn't an issue (and it is), the `O(1)` priority-queue: "Ladder Queue". Inerdial: Well insert and delete are `O(log n)`, so if you're only worried about storing the largest **n** nodes, then `O(log n)` would result.